# How to model in UML a concept that is both an entity object and an actor?

Tags: uml

How would you model in UML the following state of affairs:

A restaurant management system is used by waiters to keep track of 
servings to tables. It is also used to keep track of which waiters
serve which tables.

This means that the concept of a waiter is both an actor (as
waiters are users of the system) and an entity object (because the
system keeps track of which waiter serves which tables).

Yet according to the UML a concept can't be both an entity and an
actor because by definition "An actor is an external entity that interacts with the system."

I could always use different names to separate these concepts but that
seems artificial.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The system's entity representing a waiter  is not the same as the actual waiter who is an external agent acting on the system.

Either use different names, or put the actor and entity in separate namespaces or models.

Comment: Yes, I agree and that is what I did (used 'Table Attendant' for the actor and 'Waiter' for the entity object).

Answer (score 1):

Just because waiters use the system does not force you to name that actor as a 'waiter'.  Think about other employees who might use the system in the same way, e.g. the host/hostess or a shift manager.

Actors who are using the system are usually fulfilling a role which can shared among different actors.   You have to generalize the role the actor is playing.  If any employee could participate in that use case, the role might be 'Employee'.

Even if you didn't take that approach, you still have other synonyms to distinguish between the entity and the actor.  The actor may be 'waitstaff' and the entity could be 'server'.  It is worth the time to come up with good names especially for frequently used terms.  And if it comes down to it, forget what UML 'says' about using different names. People have been using bits and peices of UML since it came out, no one's going to shut you down if you decide to reuse a name.

What I would say is UML is trying to give you some good advice that if you are using the same name, it will cause problems later and is also an indication that there is more to the story.

Comment: Indeed, but the role is that of serving/attending tables and this is just another name of waiters. So I think in this case it is best to use different synonyms to separate the actor from the entity.